# OK to edit out non-relevant information?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes edit posts for better formatting or grammar fixes, and I was wondering if its also OK to edit out completely non-relevant information. By far the biggest offender is "I'm new to 'insert-tech-here' so I'm sorry for newb question!" but there are other things I come across (such as posting code from an entire file when asking about a local variable in a single method) and I wanted to check on what others think is best practice here.

Do I leave in useless info, or take it out so that the question is more concise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm new to 'insert-tech-here' so I'm sorry for newb question!

<strike>Kill it, KILL IT NOW!</strike> Yes, you should edit this out of questions.

You should remove, not only [things like "Hi" and "Thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), but also any non-programming context that just distracts from the issue at hand.

Just keep in mind that you should be fixing all issues in a post when performing an edit, especially if you have < 2k reputation (because then your edit needs to get approved), and, if that's the only problem, the edit might still be considered too minor.

> Things like removing the rest of the code when the issue is about a local variable in a single method.

With more than 2k reputation, such an edit would be fine, as long as **you're absolutely sure the edit is valid**, i.e. you're not removing anything required to answer the question, or additional context which might help with answering it (such as an example).

With less than 2k reputation, your edit will go through a review process, which involves it needing to get approved by 3 users who may have **absolutely no knowledge** of the domain.

You can't really expect these users to approve your edit which removes like 90% of the code (it would probably get **rejected as a "radical change"** ... or robo-approved...).

If you have less than 2k reputation, or you're not 100% sure the edit is valid, it might be best to **just leave a comment**.

---

I myself (with well over 2k reputation) rarely edit out large parts of the code, perhaps largely because the issue may *appear* to only relate to a local variable, but, in fact, significant parts of the rest of the code is also relevant ... and there are advantages to having a (more) complete program (it's testable by others).

However, I sometimes pretty much rewrite large parts of a post for the sake of clarity and brevity - while I absolutely believe these were good edits, I would've been more cautious about performing them with less than 2k reputation ... or, at the very least, **provide sufficient motivation for the change in the *Edit Summary*** (I do justify possibly questionable edits using the *Edit Summary* (as everyone should), but perhaps not in as much detail as I would've if I had to have the edit approved).

Answer (score 9):

Editing a question isn't just about editing it for grammar.  Removing any kind of noise, be that a salutation, an apology ("Sorry I don't know X", or "I'm such a noob at X"), is a good edit in my eyes.

However, if it is the only thing that was removed, it could be considered too minor.  More should be cleaned up, obviously.

Comment: Depends--if it's concise, it might be all right and "too minor" to remove.

Comment: I don't see how that could be considered "too minor" unless that's the *only* thing that was removed.  More should be cleaned up, obviously.

Comment: As long as it doesn't change the scope of the question, I think its good, but there should also be an attempt to format/proofread the whole thing