# Allow voting on edits

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, edits

Often, third party edits improve a post; sometimes they make it worse.

Currently, one can only vote on the modified post itself (where the impact is felt by the poster) or re-edit the question to rollback undesirable changes.  Neither action is "felt" by the editor, to whose behaviour one is responding.

I propose enabling users to up/down vote such edits, with a commensurate impact on *the editor's* reputation.  This would enable the community to reward/punish edits that have made a material difference to the post (whether for better or worse, respectively) and thereby incentivise good editing behaviour in the future.

It would probably be appropriate for any such voting buttons to be placed on the revision history page, which is also hidden enough for it to be likely that they are only used on edits of a sufficiently material nature.

Comment: Would people who downvote edits get a rep hit?  Or would it be similar to downvoting questions?

Comment: @bluefeet: I'm pretty ambivalent toward that point.  Perhaps you can remind me why downvoting answers negatively hits the voter, in order that I can consider whether the same reasoning would apply here?

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting) on Meta Stack Exchange

Comment: @bluefeet: In that case, if I had to decide either way, I'd probably suggest there ought to be a similar penalty for downvoting edits in order to discourage its overuse.  But I really don't have strong feelings about it.  Indeed, *one could even penalise edit-upvotes* if the use of edit-votes overall is supposed to be used only in extreme cases.

Comment: I'm genuinely interested to hear from any of the downvoters as to why they consider this to be a bad idea?

Comment: Sure, I don't like the idea. I think it would attract people to the edit queue for reputation gain who otherwise do not participate in that aspect of the site. In my view, we're better off with moderation tasks being performed by people with an altruistic motive, rather than a profit motive. I don't necessarily disagree with a disincentive or penalty to bad editors, but I don't think this is how you get there.

Comment: @Chris _we're better off with moderation tasks being performed by people with an altruistic motive_ We already have issues in the review queues with people not doing it for altruistic reasons, they are purely motivated by badges.  These robo-reviewers cause a lot of problems.

Comment: @bluefeet agreed. So adding upvotes and reputation gain would simply exacerbate that problem. At least with the badges, there is a soft cap on the amount of harm the badge-chasers cause; once they have the badge, they stop. Reputation gain from votes on edits would never stop.

Comment: @Chris: That view is founded on the premise that annoying minor robo-review editors will believe that their edits will be upvoted.  However that's unlikely to be the case, especially since edit voting will be buried on the revision history page (and probably restricted to high rep users, say 10k+).  It is **much** more likely that such edits will be repeatedly *down* voted, resulting in a *loss* of reputation - and thereby such editors will be disincentivised from making further such edits.  So rather than exacerbating the problem, this proposal ought to go some way to alleviating it.

Comment: The solution to seeing a bad edit is to perform an edit of your own. If you see a edit which actually vandalizes a post, flag it for modertion.

Comment: @meagar: Again, that only addresses half the proposal.  What about rewarding good edits?

Answer (score 3):

**The problems:**

The masses don't really look at edits. Compared to looking at posts, how often do you look at edits?

So, beyond the really, really horrible edits (which can currently be flagged in anyway), most edits are unlikely to even pick up a single vote, never mind enough to make a difference.

Unless you plan on moving them. But to where?

And how often do you see an edit so outstanding that it deserves an upvote? Most edits should be significantly improving a post, but I don't think people will really go check out the revision history to upvote most of these.

The revision history isn't front and centre. Thus edits have extremely little exposure in the long run. Beyond the initial burst of votes dealing with what just happened (for those that were there during the posting of the edit), or perhaps a (not constructive?) comment pointing out a really good/bad edit, they're unlikely to pick up votes over time.

---

**My suggestion:**

I don't think it affecting the editor's reputation is necessarily necessary - just make it so that sufficiently many downvoted edits can just get you edit banned, or send your next X edits to the Suggested Edits review queue, regardless of your reputation.

But we'll also need to make sure the downvotes are justified. The only decent way to deal with this that comes to mind is to add a review queue for edits (perhaps just pop it into the *Suggested Edits* queue).

But hey, why not just get rid of votes altogether? Let's just **let people flag individual edits, which sends the edit to the *Suggested Edits* queue**. A certain amount of flagged and then rejected edits will get you edit banned. If the edit was the most recent edit, we could revert it, otherwise we should probably not revert it if rejected (and disable "Improve").

"Too minor" edits can be a problem, as, AFAIK, we're a bit more lenient on high-reputation users making minor edits. And ["radical change"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253880/ok-to-edit-out-non-relevant-information/253886#253886) for that matter. And *Edit Summaries* that are perhaps not sufficiently motivating. Hmm...

But first, we'll need to do a bit of work on making sure people actually review properly - a good start - [Add "too minor" audits to Suggested Edits review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183977/add-too-minor-audits-to-review-queue).

---

With regard to rewarding good edits, how about an "Outstanding edit" flag (think [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), but for edits), which you have extremely few of, e.g. you get like one a week or even month, or perhaps linked to your reputation instead (e.g. one for every 500 points of reputation), awarding an "Outstanding edit" badge to the reviewing user (it gets awarded straight away - the flag just disappears into the void).

Comment: @eggyal If an edit substantially changes the content of a post, it should be a separate answer.  That is also a way for the editor to get points.

Comment: Also, moving yet more posts into the moderator queues seems to be counterintuitive: moderators are already overloaded (albeit not so much in the suggested edits queue, where very often edits that should never be approved are blindly allowed through by people who don't know any better).  Reputation has proved to be a very motivating driver of behaviour on the SE network, and I think it could be applied to better motivate editing behaviour too.

Comment: @La-comadreja: Perhaps. But if a post correctly answers the question, just with insufficient detail or inadequate references, and an editor comes along to flesh out that information or make the answer applicable to more general situations, I'd consider those edits to have materially improved the answer without necessarily warranting being posted separately.

Comment: @eggyal Perhaps we could take care of good edits with flags too - I edited a possible way into my answer.

Comment: Removed my -1 in response to your most recent edit.  I originally considered the lack of prominence of the voting buttons to be a good thing (because edit-votes are only worth encouraging in extreme cases anyway), but I take your point that people in the long-run are unlikely to review the edits to discover where responsibility lies.  Still, the review history does sit there available to be seen for a reason.

Comment: I agree that not many people look at edits, but I just posted a question and someone immediately edited it to replace a tag with a more obvious tag that I'd missed. I wanted to upvote their change to say thanks but there's no way of doing that.