# What to do about meaningless edits that get approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Today I rejected a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12646537) that was justified as "Improved formatting". However, it simply added spurious indentation that does not bear any connection with the hierarchical structure of the code (e.g. it does not indicate nesting). I didn't pay further attention until now, when I see that the edit received two reject and three approve votes and was finally approved.

Checking the [user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5771917/priya?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), they seem to systematically add random indentation to codes in different languages with no apparent logic. What is worse: these edits are being approved.

I have very little experience with "meta stuff", so I wanted to check how to deal with these cases. Should this user be contacted or should I simply revert the edit and get on with my life?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280649/are-we-supposed-to-flag-bad-reviews

Comment: I see this problem constantly on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/. Today, the same user tried to suggest 4 separate edits to the question; only the last one made it through. All of them were pointless. I have no idea what motivates people to do this; do they think having their username show up on the top question means something? I don't want to care but notifications bring it to my attention. Can I not flag suggested edits with prejudice as "Totally pointless, please also ban user"? Can we detect and revoke suggestion privileges after a string of rejections? It's just so annoying.

Comment: My guess is that it is just a farming tactic to get a little bit of reputation for not much effort and/or because they don't have sufficient knowledge to gain reputation from answers and questions. To be honest, I did kind of fall for that to get pass the very restrictive first privileges, like basic voting and commenting restrictions. It is quite hard to earn rep early on when you don't know much about every framework, say all the Selenium questions in Java, and the other questions are crap questions to be closed and deleted. However just randomly change stuff everywhere certainly isn't good.

Comment: I really think a lot of these edit/audit issues could be better resolved by (a) raising the number of points required for reviewers and (b) a complete points system for edits whereby bad edits can be downvoted. They'll learn.

Comment: IMHO raise a mod flag explaining the situation if it gets too out of hand; the mod will decide what to do (in this situation, probably edit-banning the user for a few days).

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12625401) is a typical edit from a low rep user making *extremely* trivial corrections - 35 in succession, so far. Most were approved.

Comment: @RadLexus That one should have been a reject & edit in my opinion (certain parts actively harmed readability and were completely incorrect; `files, ¿is there a way` turned into `files, It is there a way` for example).

Comment: We are teaching newbie editors pretty bad habits.  It is just too hard to get a *substantial* edit approved by reviewers that in general know nothing about the [tag] subject.

Comment: @HansPassant - I believe that *substantial* editing should be done primarily by OPs themselves.  If a question/answer requires a lot of improvement, it's not a good one to begin with.

Comment: Meh, there are questions that are important enough to deserve an answer.  They were just unlucky with the user that wrote it.

Comment: Seen as no else did rolled the edit back.

Comment: A couple of years ago, I proposed [Allow voting on edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253904/allow-voting-on-edits) as a means of addressing this problem—but once again nobody gave a &^$&%@.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you see someone with a pattern of spamming harmful or completely irrelevant edits, it's fine to raise a custom moderator flag and point this out. It's probably best to include links to a sampling of the worst edits so that we can quickly pull them up and judge if there's a problem.

If this is an issue, moderators can now manually ban people from contributing suggested edits for a period of time. I've done that here, because these edits were a waste of reviewer effort. If the edits are particularly bad, and I see people still approving them, I may go through and start issuing review bans as well (like I did for the series of edits pointed out by GManNickG in the comments).

If it's just one or two bad formatting edits by a single user, I wouldn't worry too much about it, but if it's a pattern of bad edits or if the edits themselves are horribly destructive, it might make sense to flag down a moderator to look at them.

Comment: Basically, only flag if it's a systemic problem not a sporadic one.

Comment: (Did you also see reason to take care of mine? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37705530/revisions) is another of  his pretty pointless edits, fairly typical of the rest.)

Comment: @RadLexus Umm... What? Not the same user... And the OP accepted that suggested edit too... What's exactly the issue with that one?

Comment: In particular, this is currently a good way to bootstrap sock puppets to 15 rep. Here are a few possible edits that are easy to find in bulk: https://github.com/cirosantilli/stack-overflow-vote-fraud-script/blob/master/puppets.md#trivial-edits

Comment: "...if it's a pattern of bad edits or if the edits themselves are horribly destructive"    I'd assumed that a series of rejections for damaging or destructive edits would raise a flag automatically. Can you clarify that in your answer?

Comment: @Nile - The system currently doesn't raise any automatic flags for rejection reasons. There might be value in something like that, but it would need to be tested to make sure it wouldn't become too noisy. The vast majority of these cases end up being handled by the system without our intervention, so we'd only need to see the ones slipping through.